# How to override BigDecimal toString() method?

Tags: java, jsp, bigdecimal, cglib

I am working on a legacy web app built with JSP. I was asked to replace double with BigDecimal in the codes. I am aware that the default toString() method of BigDecimal uses the scientific notation to render the numbers. That will be a problem when output the number on JSP page. I don't want to replace every ${obj.property} with < fmt:formatNumber type="number" ... />. So I am wondering if there is a way to override the toString() method, so it will call the **toPlainString()** instead? I tried cglib, however realised it's not for this purpose as it can only manipulate the BigDecimal generated by the Enhancer as shown below:

```
Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
    enhancer.setSuperclass(BigDecimal.class);
    enhancer.setCallback(new MethodInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public Object intercept(Object obj, Method method, Object[] args, MethodProxy proxy) throws Throwable {
            if(method.getName().equals("toString")){
                return ((BigDecimal) obj).toPlainString();
            }else{
                System.out.println(method.getName() + " called.");
                return proxy.invokeSuper(obj, args);
            }
        }
    });
    BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) enhancer.create(new Class[]{String.class}, new Object[]{"123"});
    System.out.println(bd.toString());
```

I am going to have a look of Byte Buddy and Javassit, but guess they work in a similar way as cglib.

Anyone knows a way to achieve this?

For JSP, I may get away with a customised javax.el.BeanELResolver, but still is there a way to override a standard library method in whole application?

Comment: Looks like javaagent is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `BigDecimal` directly you could extend on the class and overwrite the `toString` method in your own class. Then you just have to replace the constructor calls to use your class.

```
public class MyBigDecimal extends BigDecimal {
    public MyBigDecimal(String val) {
        super(val);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return toPlainString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach, but I get an error that BigDecimal contains abstract methods that I need to reimpliment. Trying the above in Kotlin, not sure if that makes a difference. Underlying BigDecimal implementation is Java 8.